# Grails Hibernate Custom Identifier Generator Oracle 11g

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have an Id in a domain class which is a varchar and has a sequence to it. I implemented a custom generator and added it to the mapping for the domain class Id column.

```
id column:"col_id",generator:"packagename.classname"
```

However my IdentifierGenerator needs a dataSource ref to it. When I do an Integration test for persisting the object, the generate method for id is called before the dataSource is injected into the generator class. Does anyone have working examples?

Comment: i have no solution but I wonder how you get the dataSource injected? Looking at the hibernate code, the generator is created by calling newInstance() on the class, not via spring...

Comment: Cant we inject dataSource from resources.groovy?

Comment: usually yes, but hibernate does not use spring to create the generator object, which means no automatic injection... You can use Holders.applicationContext.getBean ('dataSource') in the generate() method to get the dataSource. This is a bit ugly but may work.

Comment: oh it makes sense..I can inject the dependency,but generate method will be called before dependency is set in my custom generator.Is that correct?

Comment: Yea workaround worked.I am giving you an upvote.Is my guess correct ?

Comment: No, hibernate does call newInstance() on the generator class  completely bypassing spring. spring doesn't get any chance to inject the data source in this case. If you inject the generator into another spring bean (a service for example), spring will create the generator object and set the data source.

Comment: Thanks for explanation Martin.Where is the newInstance method you saw.Can you give me the classname.Just trying to understand the whole picture.When I override the generate method with my custom class,it does not use the injected dataSource from resource.groovy,its null.So you mean to say its not correct to inject dataSource in custom generator?Why does it not get injected when I inject it from resources.groovy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59384/discussion-between-android-and-martin-hauner).